# Why do my models shift between 100% accuracy and 60% accuracy?

Tags: python, keras, classification, conv-neural-network

I am trying to classify data as walking or running (and eventually other activities) from x,y, and z accelerometer and gyroscope data on the thigh and shank (6 features) using a 1D convolution neural network and sweeping over different parameters.

When I train and evaluate the models on my data, I sometimes get 100% accuracy and other times get 60% accuracy (there are some combinations of parameters that result in ~99%). The models don't look like they're overfitting from the training v validation loss curves, but I find it odd that I sometimes get a 100.000% and then others so low.

To see if it is always the case I train and evaluate each model 15 times and take the mean and standard deviation. Most of the parameter combinations exhibit this behavior, with some not.

For example (the value at the end is the accuracy against unseen data):

```py
>Standardize=False Filter=16 Kernel=3 Batch=32: #1: 59.701
>Standardize=False Filter=16 Kernel=3 Batch=32: #2: 100.000
>Standardize=False Filter=16 Kernel=3 Batch=32: #3: 100.000
>Standardize=False Filter=16 Kernel=3 Batch=32: #4: 99.975
>Standardize=False Filter=16 Kernel=3 Batch=32: #5: 100.000
>Standardize=False Filter=16 Kernel=3 Batch=32: #6: 40.299
>Standardize=False Filter=16 Kernel=3 Batch=32: #7: 100.000
>Standardize=False Filter=16 Kernel=3 Batch=32: #8: 59.701
>Standardize=False Filter=16 Kernel=3 Batch=32: #9: 59.701
>Standardize=False Filter=16 Kernel=3 Batch=32: #10: 100.000
>Standardize=False Filter=16 Kernel=3 Batch=32: #11: 59.701
>Standardize=False Filter=16 Kernel=3 Batch=32: #12: 100.000
>Standardize=False Filter=16 Kernel=3 Batch=32: #13: 59.701
>Standardize=False Filter=16 Kernel=3 Batch=32: #14: 59.701
>Standardize=False Filter=16 Kernel=3 Batch=32: #15: 99.975
```

This is the model I am using:

```py
    model = models.Sequential()
    model.add(Conv1D(filters=filt, kernel_size=kernel, activation='relu',
                     input_shape=(n_timesteps, n_features)))
    model.add(Conv1D(filters=filt, kernel_size=kernel, activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
    model.add(layers.Flatten())
    model.add(layers.Dense(100, activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dense(n_activities, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

    # fit network
    history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_val, y_val),
                        epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose)

    # evaluate model
    _, accuracy = model.evaluate(X_val, y_val, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=0)
```

I sweep over filter size (16, 32), kernel size (3, 5), and batch size (16,32) and I also check standardized and non standardized data.

I am also training on about 10,000+ windows of data

Does this mean that my model is wrong / not working correctly? If so, is there any fix to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### several problems of random accuracy

1. your error gradient doesn't reach initial layers! (you can check this by ploting histograms of weights in tensorboard) -> **solution:** try batchNormalization layers
2. your loss function is almost discrete, (happens in classification problems, like yours)
   -> **solution:**

   - if there is more data, try more data + more train epochs
   - if there is no other data, try to tune bata1 beta1 (moment1) parameter of adam optimizer (tuning it will give optimal convergence in almost descrete losses, usually beta1=0.5 will provide good results in CNNs) and play with learning rate, (lower learning rates have higher chance of steady accuracy per run, but lower chance of getting out of local minima in loss function (lower chance of reaching the optimal point), best way to do it, is higher learning rate with some decay (Adam optimizer doesnt need decay, this is for RMSProp and some optimizers like that).
3. batch size: usually small batch sizes make the optimizer converge to local minimas, **solution:** train with large batch sizes (128 or more) for couple of epochs, then train with lower batch sizes (but not lower that 8, which will make the results unreliable)

Comment: Thank you for the response, a few follow-up questions: 1. Where would you suggest adding batchNormalization layers and why that location? 2. I don't have more data at the moment but I am training on typically around 10,000+ samples. 3. How would I implement a decay on this adam optimizer?

Comment: @Eric 1. after Convolution layers, dense layers usually don't need it, by the way, i recommend loosing the 100 neurons dense layer, its useless (you can try and see the accuracy) 2. try higher batch sizes then 3. as I updated, Adam updates it own learning rate, which makes it not very suitable for these situations, try RMSProp with decay and learning rate of < 0.001